# How to show that $e_i \cdot Ae_j = a_{ij}$ - Matrices

Tags: matrices

Let $e_j \in R^n$ be a vector whose $j$'th component is 1 and all other components are 0.

For example, if $n=3$ then $e_2$ = $\left(\begin{matrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{matrix}\right)$

Let $A= (a_{ij}) \in M_{m,n} (R)$

How would I show that:

$e_i \cdot Ae_j = a_{ij}$

Answer (score 2):

Think about why if $v = Ae_j$, then the vector $v$ is the $j^{th}$ column of $A$. Now, think about if you have any vector $w$, why $e_i \cdot w$ will give you the $i^{th}$ entry in the vector $w$. Putting these together you can see that $e_i \cdot Ae_j$ should give you the $i^{th}$ entry of the $j^{th}$ column of $A$.

Comment: I understand. Would a worded solution like this be efficient?

Comment: Perhaps, depending on what rigor you're expected to produce. However, you can show it formulaically as well: For example, if $v = Ae_j$, let $[v]_k$ represent the $k^{th}$ element in $v$. Then by definition (of matrix multiplication), $[v]_k = \sum_{m=1}^n a_{km}[e_j]_m = \sum_{m=1}^n a_{km} \delta_{jm} = a_{kj}$. Therefore the $k^{th}$ element of $v$ is the same as the $k^{th}$ element of the $j^{th}$ column of $A$, implying that $v$ is the same as the $j^{th}$ column of $A$.